# X-Axis break for boxplot with groupplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis, boxplot

I'm currently stumped in how to proceed to get an x-axis break for my boxplot. From going through slightly related tex.stackexchange posts, I'm guessing this should be achievable with groupplot, but my boxplot doesn't display when I'm switching my code around from axis to groupplot..

To illustrate what I'd like to achieve: [image]

Any advice on this?

Working code without break and groupplot:

```
\documentclass{minimal}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
ytick=\empty,
xmin=0, xmax=4500,
xtick={0,500,1000,2500,4500},
axis x line=bottom,
axis line style={-},
axis y line=none,
enlargelimits=0.05,
height=4.0cm, width=14.0cm,
]
\addplot+[
boxplot prepared={
upper quartile=650,
        lower quartile=30,
        upper whisker=1400,
        lower whisker=0,
        median=80
},black,
] coordinates {
(0,2100)
(0,2300)
(0,2900)
(0,3400)
(0,3700)
(0,4200)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Not working code for boxplot with x-axis break:

```
\documentclass{minimal}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group name=my fancy plots,
        group size=2 by 1,
        axis line style={-},
        ytick=\empty,
    },
    width=14cm,
]
\nextgroupplot[
               xtick={0,1000,2000,3000},
               axis x discontinuity=parallel,
               axis x line=bottom,
               width=10cm]
\addplot[
boxplot prepared={
upper quartile=650,
        lower quartile=30,
        upper whisker=1400,
        lower whisker=0,
        median=80
},black,
] coordinates {
(0,2100)
(0,2300)
(0,2900)
(0,3400)
(0,3700)
(0,4200)
};         
\nextgroupplot[xmin=9500,xmax=9750,
               xtick={9500,9750},
               axis x line=bottom,
               width=2.0cm]
\addplot coordinates {(0,9600)}; 
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Working code for future reference:

```
\documentclass{minimal}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group name=my fancy plots,
        group size=2 by 1,
        horizontal sep=3pt % added
    },
    % the following are added
    scale only axis,
    height=3cm,
    ymin=0.5,ymax=1.5,
    axis y line=none,
    axis x line=bottom,
]
\nextgroupplot[
               xmin=-100,
               ymin=0.5,ymax=1.5,
               xtick={0,1000,2000,3000},
               width=10cm,
               x axis line style={-{Bar[width=15pt]}}  
]
\addplot[
mark = x , mark options = {mark color=black},
boxplot prepared={
upper quartile=650,
        lower quartile=30,
        upper whisker=1400,
        lower whisker=0,
        median=80
},black,
] coordinates {
(0,2100)
(0,2300)
(0,2900)
(0,3400)
(0,3700)
(0,4200)
};

\nextgroupplot[xmin=9300,xmax=9900,
               xtick={9500,9750},
               width=2.0cm,
               x axis line style={{Bar[width=15pt]}-}
 ]
\addplot [
mark = x, mark options = {mark color=black}]
coordinates {(9600, 1)}; 
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing your example is missing is `\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots, statistics}`, but I suppose you have those in your actual document.

There are a few things wrong in your code.

- Common options for the axes in a groupplots does not go inside the `group style`, but outside. Hence, `axis line style={-}, ytick=\empty` needs to be moved.
- You only set the width of the axis, but the aspect ratio will remain constant if you don't set the height as well. Consider also that by default the width and height of an axis will be set to 45pt less than the lengths specified, to make room for axis labels. Add `scale only axis` to make the lengths apply to the axis box itself, otherwise a 2cm wide axis becomes quite small.
- In the coordinate plot in the second axis you've swapped the x- and y-value.
- An `axis discontinuity` is always placed at the start of the axis line, but as you've split it into two axes, you don't need this. Instead I changed the arrow type for the axis lines with e.g. `x axis line style={-|}` to add the lines. (Or add `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` and use `x axis line style={-{Bar[width=15pt]}}` to get a longer bar.)

I think I made some other adjustments as well, those were the major things I think.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots, statistics}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={
        group name=my fancy plots,
        group size=2 by 1,
        horizontal sep=3pt % added
    },
    % the following are added
    scale only axis,
    height=3cm,
    ymin=0.5,ymax=1.5,
    axis y line=none,
    axis x line=bottom,
]
\nextgroupplot[
               xmin=-100,
               xtick={0,1000,2000,3000},
               width=10cm,
               x axis line style={-{Bar[width=15pt]}}  
]
\addplot[
boxplot prepared={
upper quartile=650,
        lower quartile=30,
        upper whisker=1400,
        lower whisker=0,
        median=80
},black,
] coordinates {
(0,2100)
(0,2300)
(0,2900)
(0,3400)
(0,3700)
(0,4200)
};

\nextgroupplot[xmin=9350,xmax=9900,
               xtick={9500,9750},
               width=2.0cm,
               x axis line style={{Bar[width=15pt]}-}
 ]
\addplot coordinates {(9600, 1)}; 
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved it all for me! Weirdly enough, the coordinates are actually not swapped for the fits groupplot (I think this stems from the boxplot being horizontal). Had to tweak that a little bit further to make the points from the first groupplot show up again (I'll edit my original post with that). Thanks again!

Comment: @ThS Yeah, that's just how boxplots work I think. Instead of the tweak you used, you can try `\addplot +[boxplot prepared...` instead of `\addplot [boxplot prepared...`. Note the extra `+`, which means that plot options are appended to the default ones, instead of replacing the default ones.

Comment: good to know! thank you!